# How do I list all member groups in Umbraco?

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am currently trying to create a page where I have a list of all the groups in the the Umbraco member area.

Most of what is returned when I google for an answer is how to get all the groups for a specific user, however this is not what I want, I would like all the groups listed that are available for all members.

I guess the alternative is to create a user that has permission for all the groups and then loop through that member's groups, but this would require me to ensure that this member is added to every new group I create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer for anyone looking (Thank-you Stack Overflow for your rubber duck effect!)

```
@{
  string[] Roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
}
<ul>
  @foreach (string role in Roles) {
    <li>@role</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method on the `MemberService` which gets all of the Umbraco Member roles:

```
var roles = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetAllRoles();
```

Read about this method [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/memberservice#getallroles).

I can't figure out from looking at the source of Umbraco if this method just uses `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()`. I would probably recommend using the Umbraco method as it allows you to switch out the default membership provider without needing to change all of the method calls in the views.